# Add numpy array in blockwise

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array generated by some earlier code which needs to be added blockwise.
For example, array `a` has 32 entries and should be added such that the new array `b` has 4 entries and `b[0]` has numbers 0-7, `b[1]` has 8-15 and so on. See example below of how to do it manually.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.rand(32)
b = np.zeros(4)
b[0] = np.sum(a[0:8])
b[1] = np.sum(a[8:16])
b[2] = np.sum(a[16:24])
b[3] = np.sum(a[24:32])
```

Now I know that I can do the summation using a for loop, but I was hoping for something more fancy, as I am working with rather large arrays. I am aware of numpy's great slicing magic, so I imagine something like this could be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
#import random
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(11) # random.seed doesnt affect numpy computation as pointed out in the comments 

a = np.random.rand(32)
b = np.zeros(4)
a = np.reshape(a, (4,-1))
b = np.sum(a, axis=1)
```

Comment: What is the `-1` means?

Comment: One of the dimensions in `reshape` can be `-1`. In this case, the value is inferred from the length of the array and the remaining dimensions. Complete doc here https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html#numpy-reshape

Comment: This works great, thanks. Only tiny improvement would be to use `np.random.seed`, as currently your seed does not affect numpy and every run will get different results. Note that this may be version dependent, I recall some libraries directly using `random` its internal state, but at least recent versions of numpy keep track of their own state, unaffected by other packages.

Comment: Thanks, will update the answer accordingly.